# How to get the text from a selected row on Winforms DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, windows-mobile-6.5

This seems like it would be easy but I can't find a way to retrieve the text from the selected row on a DataGrid. The grid is single row selected only - no multiple row selection is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. One way is

string val = (string)dataGrid1[1, 1]; // cell 1, row 1

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the text of the entire row (as opposed to the existing answer that shows how to get a single value from a DataGrid):

```
string str = "";
int row = datagrid.CurrentRowIndex;
int col = 0;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        str += datagrid[row,col].ToString() + "|";
        col++;
    }
    catch
    {
        break;
    }
}
```